# I can't find where to put these options, hence no sock file

Tags: mariadb

I have installed mariadb-server and after a lot of struggling, I managed to get it to re/start without errors. However, there's no sock file so I can't even log in. It also doesn't show in netstat -antlp output. I have client.cnf, server.cnf, mysql-clients.cnf and spider.cnf. I put in the below in server.cnf under [mysqld], [server] and [mariadb] and restarted after each time, but no luck. Where do I need to put them?

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mariadb.pid
max_allowed_packet=128M
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I wound up uninstalling mariadb and installing mysql because the same thing kept happening every time I attempted to install mariadb.